# How do I shrink a partition on Windows, it seems broken?

Tags: windows, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Someone from Microsoft told me you can always shrink down the partition the most it can, is that true?](https://superuser.com/questions/59738/someone-from-microsoft-told-me-you-can-always-shrink-down-the-partition-the-most)

Hello. I'm using Windows Vista Home Premium 32 bit.

After managing my software moving it to some other partition for another OS, I have a partition table that is a bit **bizarre**. In fact, for example, I can reduce the C: partition to only 14 GB (instead of 70 GB), and I can't add those 14 GB to the partition F:.

So, I ask to you if there are some ways to fix my partition table, without touching the actual OS. (Maybe working when the OS start, or in the pro-visionary modality).

I think this is an hard or maybe impossible request, but I'm looking for a solution I could try!

I remember in the past I use Partition Magic, and sometimes it works for this kind of stuff.
(But, sometimes, not at all hehe).

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great tool that I use to shrink, expand, or even delete partitions is [GPartEd](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) (Gnome Partition Editor). The data center I work at uses this tool sometimes too (it's trusted). I would just advise that you attempt to backup your precious data first because I have had a computer BSOD on me after using GPartEd before.

Good luck.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to back-up, as files need to be moved (as pointed out in the possible duplicate) by third-party software it might rarely happen that something wrong does occur.

Answer (score 2):

Go grab a copy of [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) (Free), have a read up and see if it helps.

*"TestDisk is powerful free data recovery software! It was primarily designed to help recover lost partitions and/or make non-booting disks bootable again when these symptoms are caused by faulty software, certain types of viruses or human error (such as accidentally deleting a Partition Table). Partition table recovery using TestDisk is really easy. "*

Good luck